# Match an specific expression not between parenthesis in C#

Tags: c#, regex

as shown in below I have a string which is contain serial number of some items inside or *out of parenthesis*. How can I match items just *out of parenthesis*?

```
string text = "RRUS 2217 B7    (RRUS 2217 B7)";

string pattern = "[^(]RR?US? ?2217 ?B7";

foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

but output in console is as below:

```
RRUS 2217 B7
RRUS 2217 B7
```

Comment: Try looking behind: `string pattern = @"(?<!\([A-Z]*)RR?US? ?[0-9]{4} ?B7";`

Comment: One way could be to match what you don't want and capture what you do want `\(RR?US? ?2217 ?B7\)|(RR?US? ?2217 ?B7)` in a capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Try *looking behind*: match every `RR?US? ?2217 ?B7` pattern unless it preceeds with parenthesis and letters `(?<!\([A-Z]*)`:

```
        string text = "RRUS 2217 B7    (RRUS 2217 B7)";

        string pattern = @"(?<!\([A-Z]*)RR?US? ?2217 ?B7";

        foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
```

Comment: what does "(?<!\([A-Z]*)" mean in RegEx ?

Comment: @یـوسـف نـیـری: `(?<!([A-Z]*)` is a *negative look behind*: is **not** preceeded by ``([A-Z]*` https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Actually, *not **immediately** preceeded by*.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern starts with a word character. Another option could be to make use of the negative lookbehind `(?<!\()` to assert what is on the left is not a `(` and use a word boundary `\b` at the start of the match:

```
(?<!\()\bRR?US? ?2217 ?B7
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\()` Negative [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert what is on the left is not `(`
- `\b` [Word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `RR?US? ?2217 ?B7` Match your pattern

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%28%29%5cbRR%3fUS%3f+%3f2217+%3fB7&i=RRUS+2217+B7++++%28RRUS+2217+B7%29) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/AtjkKF)

Another way could be to match what you don't want and to capture in a group what you do want:

```
\(RR?US? ?2217 ?B7\)|(RR?US? ?2217 ?B7)
```

Comment: what does (?<!\()\b mean in RegEx ?

Comment: @یـوسـفنـیـری This part `(?<!()` is a negative lookbehind and `\b` is a word boundary. I have added an explanation.